# Form collection is not retrieving the form input values from a replace div

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, submit

I am binding a model to a view in ASP.NET MVC. The model is a collection object. At my first submit I am getting the input values in my form collection.

After the form submit, I replacing the div in the from with a partial view

```
$.post("/formDetails/CheckValid", $('#Form').serializeArray(), function (htmlResult) 
{
    $('#divtoReplace').html('');
    $('#divtoReplace').html(htmlResult);
}
```

But after replacing the div, I am unable to get the input values from the replaced div through
the jQuery submit.

Please help me on sorting this issue.

Comment: Can you post the html/razor content of the original form, and the replacement partial ?

Comment: This happens only in IE browser. Othere browsers I am able to get the values.

Comment: I had a problem with IE caching ajax request [here how to stop it](http://www.codecouch.com/2009/01/how-to-stop-internet-explorer-from-caching-ajax-requests/)

Comment: Its not a IE caching problem. Problem is when replacing a div within a form with a partial view and the partial view contains some input tags. I am unable to retrieve the input tag values from the partial view replaced using form collection.

Comment: are you selecting the inputs every time or are you putting the inputs in variables and using them?

Comment: just i am adding the values into hidden fields and trying to get using  form collection. but those hidden field values in the replaced div(i.e., partial view) are not obtainable in the form collection.